# How can i wait for a value to be set from useEffect?

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, use-effect, react-usememo

We are using useMemo and useEffect when fetching an array of data. In the first file im setting a const with results from the hook (second file). But the results gets set twice and the first time the result is an empty object.

I would need it to be set after the useEffect has done its job.

We have 2 js files

- first.js
- second.js

First.js

```
const dataArray = useGetDataArray({ name, id });
console.log("Data Array: ", dataArray);
```

Second.js

```
export const useGetDatArray = ({ name, id } = {}) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  const index = useMemo(() => {
    console.log("in useMemo");
    const client = thirdPartyProvider;

    return client;
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("in useEffect");
   
    index
      .search(name, {
        numberOfResults: 12,
      })
      .then(res => setData(_.get(res, "result")));
  }, [index]);

  return data;
};
```

My console looks like this

```
"in useMemo "
"Data Array:"  Object {  }
"in useEffect" 
"Data Array:" Array(12) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
```

This is how i would like if possible

```
"in useMemo" 
"in useEffect" 
"Data Array:" Array(12) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
```

Comment: You can't. A render will occur every time state is changed. I also recommend setting the initial value to be an array instead.

Comment: Adding a dependency in useEffect?

Comment: @evolutionxbox That what i was afraid of.

Comment: @RicardodePaula i have a dependency, the index variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First.js

```
useEffect(async () => {
  await useGetDataArray({ name, id });
  const dataArray = myContainer.data;
  console.log("Data Array: ", dataArray);
}, []);
```

Second.js

```
export const useGetDatArray = ({ name, id } = {}) => {
  const index = useMemo(() => {
    console.log("in useMemo");
    const client = thirdPartyProvider;

    return client;
  }, []);

  useEffect(async () => {
    console.log("in useEffect");
    await myContainer.getData(index, name);
  }, [index]);
};
```

Container.js

```
function myContainer(){
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  const getData = async (index, name) => {
    const indexData = await index.search(name, { numberOfResults: 12 });
    if (indexData) {
        await setData(indexData);
    }
  }

  return { data, getData };
}
export const MyContainer = createContainer(myContainer);
```

Comment: `Data Array` will still be called first, there is no answer, because you shouldn't await the hook